# load user-written minor mode in a specific major mode

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode

I'm trying to use a very simple minor mode I've written to personnalize the appearance of the buffer when I'm running R in ESS.

Basically, I've set the linespacing in my init file to increase it and want this line spacing be turned to `nil` when I load ESS.

Here is the `.el` file I've written so far.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode ess_XXX-mode
  "Personal configuration of ESS'"
  :lighter " ess_XXX")

(setq line-spacing 1)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 110)

(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(ess_XXX-mode " ess_XXX"))

(provide 'ess_XXX-mode)
```

When I eval the buffer, this works but on all buffers.
When I run Emacs, I'm not able to load the minor-mode...

I've added the following in my init file

```lisp
(require 'ess_XXX-mode)
(add-hook 'iESS-mode-hook 'ess_XXX-mode)
```

but again this works on all the buffers without any restriction. It seems Emacs cannot find the minor mode (I've stored the `.el` file in my `.emacs.d/` directory).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a minor mode to customize the appearance of a major mode. You can do that more simply with a function called from the mode hook:

```lisp
(defun my-ess-hook ()
    (setq line-spacing 1))

(add-hook 'iESS-mode-hook 'my-ess-hook)
```

`(set-face-attribute 'default ...)` will change the default face for the whole Emacs frame, it doesn't apply to a single mode or buffer alone. I'm not sure there is a straightforward way to customize the default face for one buffer or mode only.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ess_XXX-mode.el` file needs to be in a directory which is present in your <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `load-path` list.

Your `~/.emacs.d` directory is not present in that list by default ([and you should not add it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/warning-message-about-load-path)).

If necessary, create a new directory such as `~/.emacs.d/lisp` and add that to your `load-path`.

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
```

Comment: OK, now my minor mode loads every time I launch Emacs. It seems I'm not able to differentiate the loading to a specific mode.

Comment: Of course -- `require` is for loading libraries.  If you want to load-on-demand then use `autoload`.

Answer (score 2):

See the doc string for `define-minor-mode`: `(define-minor-mode MODE DOC [KEYWORD VAL ... &rest BODY])`. IOW, the code that should be executed when the mode is enabled (and *also when the mode is disabled*) has to be included as the `BODY` in the `define-minor-mode` form. Something like this:

```el
(define-minor-mode ess_XXX-mode
  "Personal configuration of ESS'"    ; DOC
  :lighter " ess_XXX"                 ; KEYWORD-VALUE pairs
  ;; here comes the BODY
  (cond
    (ess_XXX-mode
     ;; mode was turned on
     ... code to execute when the mode is turned on ...
       )
    (t
     ;; mode was turned off
     ... code to execute when the mode is turned off ...
       )))
```

Many minor modes do not need a `BODY` at all, but since you are modifying global variables, it seems to me that yours does.