# how to load a file in init.el

Tags: load

I have a

~/.emacs.d/init.el

which includes:-

(load-file "blabla.el")

blabla.el is in ~/.emacs.d/

When I start emacs I get this error:-

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, /root/blabla.el

I can use a full path to load the file, but do I need to? I thought emacs would look in emacs home directory (~/.emacs.d/) to find files. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

`load-file` needs an absolute file name.  If you *don't* give it an absolute path, it will have to generate one based on the current buffer's `default-directory` which isn't going to be what you want:

```
$ cd /
$ emacs -Q --batch --eval "(load-file \"foo.el\")"
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, /foo.el

$ cd /tmp
$ emacs -Q --batch --eval "(load-file \"foo.el\")"
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, /tmp/foo.el
```

> I thought emacs would look in emacs home directory (~/.emacs.d/) to find files.

You don't want that either.  Emacs will not look in `~/.emacs.d` by default when loading lisp files (and see [Warning message about load-path.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9877) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/24779041 regarding the fact that Emacs will complain if you try to make it do so).

In code, you would usually use either `(load "foo")` or `(require 'foo)` to load a `foo.el[c]` library with Emacs looking for it in the directories listed in the `load-path` variable.

I suggest reading:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Lisp Libraries`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)How Programs Do Loading`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `require`

Comment: I have added a lisp sub-directory, added it to the load-path and moved blabla.el to it. C-h v load-path shows ~/.emacs.d/lisp as the first directory. However when starting emacs I still get 

|File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, /root/blabla.el 

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm *guessing* you're still using `load-file` which hasn't changed its behaviour since I described it.

Comment: Oops. You're correct. Many thanks.
I'm new to all this. I thought you needed to 'load-file' rather than 'load'.

Comment: All of the functions for loading files ultimately call `load`, so anything that you can do with the other functions you can also do with `load` (depending on the arguments you pass).  There's no harm in using one of the other functions if its behaviour is actually what you want, but in lisp code you can always use `load` directly.